# ASP.NET Passing ClientID to javascript causes slow rendering in IE

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a web user control containing several textboxes. Some of those textboxes have javascript click events.

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="myControl.ascx.vb" Inherits="myControl" ClassName="myControl" %>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function textbox1_Click(textbox1, textbox2, textbox3, textbox4) {
        //processing
    }

    function textbox2_Click(textbox1, textbox2, textbox3, textbox4) {
        //processing
    }

    function textbox3_Click(textbox1, textbox2, textbox3, textbox4) {
        //processing
    }

    function textbox4_Click(textbox1, textbox2, textbox3, textbox4) {
        //processing
    }

</script>

<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="textbox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="textbox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="textbox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

In the code behind I add the click events like so.

```
Partial Class myControl
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        textbox1.Attributes.Add("onClick", "textbox1_Click(" & textbox1.ClientID & ", " & textbox2.ClientID & ", " & textbox3.ClientID & ", " & textbox4.clientID & ");")
        textbox2.Attributes.Add("onClick", "textbox2_Click(" & textbox1.ClientID & ", " & textbox2.ClientID & ", " & textbox3.ClientID & ", " & textbox4.clientID & ");")
        textbox3.Attributes.Add("onClick", "textbox3_Click(" & textbox1.ClientID & ", " & textbox2.ClientID & ", " & textbox3.ClientID & ", " & textbox4.clientID & ");")
        textbox4.Attributes.Add("onClick", "textbox4_Click(" & textbox1.ClientID & ", " & textbox2.ClientID & ", " & textbox3.ClientID & ", " & textbox4.clientID & ");")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now I have a page that has a large amount of these controls added to it via a place holder.

```
For x as Integer = 0 to 300
    Dim newRow As myControl = LoadControl("myControl.ascx") 
    myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(newRow)
Next
```

The problem is this page is very slow to render in IE. The page is taking about 10 seconds to render in IE9. You can watch as the user controls progressively get rendered on the page and IE is nearly unresponsive until the rendering is complete. I tried IE8 and it was even slower. Firefox and Chrome of course load instantly.

I found that this performance issue is directly related to passing the clientID's to the javascript functions. If I remove the passing of all variables to the click events it loads fine in IE.

```
Public Class myControl
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        textbox1.Attributes.Add("onClick", "textbox1_Click();")
        textbox2.Attributes.Add("onClick", "textbox2_Click();")
        textbox3.Attributes.Add("onClick", "textbox3_Click();")
        textbox4.Attributes.Add("onClick", "textbox4_Click();")
    End Sub
End Class
```

I tried getting the the clientID's in the javascript functions themselves like so.

```
var mytextbox = document.getElementById('<%= textbox1.ClientID %>');
```

This doesn't work, it always gives me the ID from the last dynamically added user control.

Is there anyway I can get this to render in IE in a reasonable amount of time? Maybe there is another way to achieve what Im doing? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you try adding the textboxes as HTML elements in the code behind file with server side code to see if the issue is only caused by adding those attributes or by some internal processes when converting the strongly typed objects back to HTML element?

Comment: Try to use ClientIDMode="Static" so user will be responsible for maintaining unique IDS, server will not generate unique ids and ids will the same that is provided by user

Comment: @JanW. Can you elaborate on how to do this, Im not sure what you mean. Adding the attributes doesn't cause the issue but passing the clientID's to the javascript onclick functions causes the issue.

Comment: This is C# code but you'll get the drift. If the controls are defined dynamically as an array in the code behind you could add the following to the aspx file to see if it is the grabbing of the client ID or the adding of the attribute:     <% foreach (var textbox in TextBoxes)
   {
       %>  <input type="text" id="<%=textbox.ClientID %>"/>   <%
   } %>    ... With this method I could add hundred boxes to display in less than a second in IE

Comment: @shadow I tried changing the ClientIDMode property to Static but this causes me to lose reference to the textbox values I am using in the javascript functions. I also tried all other ClientIDMode possibilities and none of them helped.

Comment: I believe you're passing IDs incorrectly, they have to be included in single quotes, e.g. `"textbox1_Click('" & textbox1.ClientID & "', `. Not that it should directly affect performance, but give it a try

Comment: @rylan37 If you use ClientIDMode property then id given by you in control will be the actual clientID

Comment: @JanW. I added the textboxes dynamically in the code behind of the user control. Don't have an aspx file since it is a user control, it is ascx. I try adding inputs with `<input type="text" id="<%=textBoxes(0).ClientID%>"/>` but I get 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: @YuriyGalanter You can pass the ID's with or without the quotes. With the quotes it just requires an extra step in the javascript using `document.getElementById`. Either way has the same performance issues though.